# svg rounded-corner clipping in firefox (works fine in ie9 and chrome)

Tags: css, firefox, svg, rounded-corners

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me with the following problem:

When rounded corners are added to svg canvas, both chrome and ie9 perform the clipping correctly. Firefox (v13.0), however, ignores the rounded corners. I could do the clipping manually in svg, but I wonder if there is a better solution.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <svg id="paper" version="1.1" width="300" height="300" style="border-radius: 20px; background-color: red;">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="400" height="400" fill="blue">
    </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=763133 on schedule for firefox 16 currently.

Comment: looking forward to the fix :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also just make the svg rect have the same rounded corners.

```
<svg id="paper" version="1.1" width="300" height="300" style="border-radius: 20px; background-color: red;">
  <rect id="background" width="100%" height="100%" rx="20" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```

Or if you need the clipping, something like what you suggested:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<svg id="paper" version="1.1" width="300" height="300" clip-path="url(#clip)">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="clip">
            <rect id="background" width="100%" height="100%" rx="20" fill="red"/>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red"/>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained my goals. I am working on a project that requires zooming and panning, so stuff sticking out of the container is unavoidable. I will probably just go with clippling. Thanks for the code!